# Bootstrap CSS: Editing page navigator

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I'm having a problem with a page navigator in CSS. I'm using your normal Boostrap tables, and for tables with multiple pages, I'm using a regular pageable attribute. The number of elements on these tables can change, though, and sometimes there will only be one page or even zero elements. Is there a way I can gray out the page navigator when there is only one, or zero, pages?

Answer (score 0):

you can add to any "`li`" element the class "`disabled`"

Answer (score 0):

A friend helped me figure it out. Instead of graying out the page numbers, he just showed me how to add a conditional into the proper typescript file.

```
EventName(): void {
    if((<any>this).object.totalPages() <= 1) {
        (<any>this).pager.element.hide();
    }
}
```